# Is it possible to do all hat throws without using motion controls?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

The moves listed out in the **Basic Actions** action guide suggest that most hat throws can only be performed using motion controls.

- Upward Throw
- Downward Throw
- Spin Throw
- Homing Cap Throw
- (throwing farther)

However if you are clever enough, you would have found that you could do the **Spin Throw** using controls alone by first performing a **Spin** followed by throwing your hat. I've also discovered that you can perform a **Downward Throw** by first doing a **Ground Pound** immediately followed by a throw.

Most of the time, I'm playing in portable mode where the joycon are connected to the screen. Trying to do these moves this way is really awkward at times and would rather not have to do it.

Is it possible to do the other hat throws without using motion?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. The homing cap throw specifically is throw + shake. I would love to be proven wrong, but frustratingly even after having turned off motion controls, this is still a problem. My only real gripe with the game.

Comment: The motion controls option only enables/disables motion controlled aiming, it has no impact on motion controls tied to throwing Cappy.

Comment: I know you can get around the "shake to speed up" by mashing X or Y; at least when climbing poles.  Haven't really figured out a similar way to control cappy though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I could tell, it's not possible to do *all* of the hat throws without using motion. They really wanted to make motion as part of the game, despite how many players generally dislike them.

I tried to find alternate ways to do the moves listed above, but it doesn't seem like there's any other combination of moves that I've been able to find than to use motion.

- Upward Throw - Motion only.
- Downward Throw - **Ground Pound** followed by throw.
- Spin Throw - **Spin** followed by throw.
- Homing Cap Throw - Motion only.
- (throwing farther) - Motion only. You can however simulate this by doing the **Downward Throw** on flat ground. Cappy will be able to go twice the normal throwing distance.

Comment: I actually like the motion/gesture controls, but wish there were alternatives because it's a bit awkward when you're playing on a flight over the pacific